# Testing SVGR as React Component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs

Getting a warning when running test on svg component.  It's not causing the test to fail but trying to get it cleaned up. Using SVGR to use svg files as react components. I believe the issue is Jest isn't able to see the svgr configuration in webpack, but not sure how to fix it.

**Warning**

```
  console.error
    Warning: <ReactComponent /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
        at ReactComponent
        at Icon (/code/common/javascript/components-2.0/lib/brand/Icon/index.tsx:9:11)
```

```
import { SvgIndexable } from "./Icon.types";

import { ReactComponent as ArrowRight } from "./svg/arrow-right.svg";

const iconNames: SvgIndexable = {
  "arrow-right": ArrowRight,
}

export default iconNames
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import className from "classnames";

import { IconTypes } from "./Icon.types";
import iconNames from "./Icon.Components";
import styles from "./Icon.module.scss";

const Icon: React.FC<IconTypes> = (props: IconTypes): JSX.Element| null => {
  const { id, name, extraClass, color = "black", size = "medium" } = props;
  const iconClasses = className(styles[size], styles[color], extraClass);

  const IconComponent = iconNames[name];

  if (typeof iconNames[name] !== "undefined") {
    return React.createElement(
      iconNames[name],
      {
        id:id,
        className:iconClasses,
        "data-testid":`test__${id}-icon`,
      },
      null
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export default Icon;
```

**jest.config.json**

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/lib/$1",
    "components-2.0": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/components-2.0
    "\\.(pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|xml|manifestjson|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/components-2.0/svgrMock.js"
  },
```

**svgrMock.js**

```
import * as React from "react";

export default "SvgrURL";
export const ReactComponent = "div";
```